# I want to swipe through a lot of flashcards without changing fragments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to learn Japanese with flashcards. For this, I created three fragments:

This is "Start Fragment":
[image: Start Fragment]

When I click on "Words", I go to "Fragment01":
[image: Fragment01]

Then, clicking on "N5" brings me to "Fragment02", which is where all my words are shown:
[image: Fragment02]

this is my main activity:

```
package com.example.testapp2;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        // Create new fragment and transaction
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); // getSupportFragmentManager() doesn't work
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        StartFragment startFragment = new StartFragment();

        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, startFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        //refresh_word();

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.article, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);*/
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Did'ya think there'd be somthin'?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public Word[] japanese_words = {};//HERE I HAVE DELETED ALL THE WORDS BECAUSE YOU  WOULD HAVE SCROLLED FOR TOO LONG, BUT IT WORKS FINE

    int word_counter = 0;

    public void onSelectFragment(View view)
    {
        //I deleted the contents because it works too (it basically switches between StartFragment, Fragment01 and Fragment02)
    }

    public void refresh_word()//THIS WORKS TOO, SO I DELETED IT
    {
        // refresh the word on screen so that it matches the word counter and
        // the preferences of the user
    }

    public boolean canContinue()
    {
        //WORKS TOO
    }

    public void prev_word(View view)
    {
        //WORKS TOO
    }

    public void next_word(View view)
    {
        //WORKS TOO
    }
}
```

this is my Fragment_02 xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHiragana"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/msg"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEnglish"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="@string/msg"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewKanji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/msg"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="@string/msg"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="prev_word"
            android:text="@string/prev" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="next_word"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works fine, as it should be:

When I click on next, it shows the next word, and previous shows the previous word WITHOUT CHANGING FRAGMENTS

I want to be able to delete the "next" and "previous" buttons and instead swipe through my words (I have 700 words in total)

I have been searching for a solution for a few days now, but the only thing I found involves changing fragments

HOW CAN I SWIPE BETWEEN WORDS WITHOUT CHANGING FRAGMENTS???

Answer (score 0):

You can Swipe through simple views by using a library like : https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

You'll have to provide it an adapter that will generate Views for given list of data.